# chromium browser wrap mode

Tags: vim, chromium

I have a 21 Inch desktop on which normally two windows are opened side by side. On opening a web page I have to scroll horizontally to view the contents. Is there a way to wrap the web page content as there is in vim 
i.e

```
:set wrap
```

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use view-source:http://...... then you don't have to scroll horizontally, just vertically.

Comment: view-source opens the source of the web page . I m interested in avoiding horizontal scrolling on the web page not on the source page.

Comment: most of them are controlled by css on the page, if you really want to read the text content, view-source is the way. The other way to get an addon to use the user-agent string of a mobile phone and hope the site will give a mobile view. or use a text browser like lynx or links.

Comment: you can also do this chrome.exe  --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 0.5; en-us) AppleWebKit/522+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/419.3", some sites will give you a mobile page.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but I m looking for something different . I guess I will have to manage with vimium plugin.

Comment: I like viewing the web as source... after a while all you see are blonde... brunette.... redhead...

Answer (score 0):

[Some](http://evernote.com/clearly/), [tools](http://www.readability.com/), [exist](http://www.apple.com/safari/whats-new.html#read) that allow you to read the content of a web page in a more manageable way.

Or you could simply disable css altogether for a given webpage with Pendule or some other Chrome extension.

The funny thing is that the www *and* HTML are actually designed around the utterly beautiful principles of accessibility, usability, interoperability and the ability to read the damn content of a damn web page comfortably, in whatever damn client I happen to use.

But our clients don't give a damn about all that and they are those who pay us to design/build their websites. *That*'s why you (and I) are forced to scroll horizontally when the window is too narrow to display their damn right bar.

Comment: hmm right , So I have installed this vimium plugin in chrome . Atleast I can bear to scroll horizontally/vertically with keys :P.